# how to apply pseudo classes (nth-of-type) in IE8 and below browsers

Tags: css

Is there any way to apply pseudo classes like (nth-of-type) in IE8 and below browsers?

I tried using plugins like jquery-extended-selectors.js in this link [this link contains the js file and description to support pseudo classes like (nth-of-type) in IE8 and below browsers?]

I could not apply the pseudo classes yet by using the above plugin.

Is there any other way of applying pseudo classes in IE8 and below browsers? If so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

FOR `IE8 CSS`  below css use

```
       /* equivalent to li:nth-child(1) */
        .classname> li:first-child {

        // your css code

        }

    /* equivalent to li:nth-child(2) */
     .classname> li:first-child + li {

     // your css code

        }
 /* equivalent to li:nth-child(3) */
     .classname> li:first-child + li + li{

     // your css code

        }
 /* equivalent to li:nth-child(4) */
     .classname> li:first-child + li + li + li{

     // your css code

        }
```

Comment: try this i have used this css my own site. its working perfectly

Comment: How would you go with `li:nth-child(odd)`? I'm pretty sure that there's a filler library in JavaScript that can actually make the native code work rather nicely.

Comment: Are you kidding me? I'm asking how you would accomplish it in IE using your method!

Comment: This didn't answer the question at all.

Comment: This works, but isn't particularly clean, and isn't useful if you need 40 or 50, or as @MadaraUchiha has suggested any kind of non numeric (or compound – 2n+1 etc) declaration.

Answer (score 2):

I use selectivizr. Selectivizr is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8. Simply include the script in your pages and selectivizr will do the rest.

http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: It says on their [page](http://selectivizr.com/#how) that `:first-of-type` and  `:nth-of-type()` won't work with JQuery, or am I wrong? Or you aren't using JQ?